# Linux Script Nested if-statements giving syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I am trying to nest multiple if-statements as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start_server.sh
# 
# Use this script to start the MarketDataTransmitter.
#
# Usage: ./start_server.sh    Starts the MarketDataTransmitter.

reset=$(tput sgr0)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
echo
directory=$(ls -l)
check_exist=$(awk -v a="$directory" -v b="MarketDataTransmitter" 'BEGIN { print index(a, b) }')
if [ "$check_exist" = "0" ]; then
  # MarketDataTransmitter is not present.
  echo "${red}[ERROR]${reset} Could not start ${yellow}MarketDataTransmitter${reset}."
  echo "        ${yellow}MarketDataTransmitter${reset} could not be found."
else
  # MarketDataTransmitter is present.
  processes=$(ps -ef | grep -i "MarketDataTransmitter" | grep -v "grep" | grep -v "bash" | awk '{ print $8 }')
  check_run=$(awk -v a="$processes" -v b="MarketDataTransmitter" 'BEGIN { print index(a, b) }')
  if [ "$check_run" = "0" ]; then
    # MarketDataTransmitter is not running.
    if [ -e "srv.log" ]; then
      if [ -s "srv.log" ]; then
        if [ -d "logs" ]; then
          date_time=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
          new_log_name="srv_$date_time.log"
          mv srv.log $new_log_name
          mv $new_log_name logs
        else
          mkdir logs
          date_time=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
          new_log_name="srv_$date_time.log"
          mv srv.log $new_log_name
          mv $new_log_name logs
        fi
      else
        echo "srv.log is empty and will be removed."
        rm -rf srv.log
      fi
    else
      # No srv.log but this is to start MarketDataTransmitter so we can ignore.
    fi
    ./MarketDataTransmitter > srv.log &
    echo "${yellow}MarketDataTransmitter${reset} has been started."
  else
    # MarketDataTransmitter is already running.
    echo "${red}[ERROR]${reset} Could not start ${yellow}MarketDataTransmitter${reset}."
    echo "        ${yellow}MarketDataTransmitter${reset} is already running."
  fi
fi
echo
```

However it is giving me syntax complaints saying:

syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

on the very last 'fi'

Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

[EDIT] Full code has been posted.

Comment: Can you post your actual code? Most likely you have a syntax error due to missing one of the `then` statements, or too many `fi`s or something similar

Comment: Hi Jarek, thanks for the quick reply. Full code has been posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an `else` statement and `fi` statement with nothing between them on lines 44-46 (just a comment between them). In bash, you need to have some statement in the body of that else block, or take the else block out.